# Rails Async Active Job doesn't execute code, while inline does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

Does the :async queue adapter actually do anything?

:inline, which is what is default in Rails 4, processes jobs built with ActiveJob, uh... inline, in the current execution thread. Async, shouldn't. It should use the ConnectionPool to not run it in the current thread, and that's ideally what would be happening. It'd run perform outside of the current execution thread.

But nothing executes it.

I've pored through the docs, and the only thing I can fathom is is that :async, unlike :inline, doesn't execute tasks, and expects you to build a system around execution locally. I have to manually perform `perform` on all jobs in order to get them to execute locally. When I set the adapter to :inline, it works just fine without having to execute.

Is there some configuration issue I'm missing that's preventing async from working correctly (like ActionCable?).

Does it not work if executed from a rake task (or the console?).

It works fine with :sidekiq/:resque, but I don't want to be running these locally all the time.

`Rails by default comes with an "immediate runner" queuing implementation. That means that each job that has been enqueued will run immediately.`

This is kind of what's cueing me in there being something wrong. I have jobs that are sitting in a queue somewhere that just don't run. What could be stopping this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I discovered. With the advent of concurrent-ruby, rake tasks aren't set up to handle this.

If you read in the documentation, it says with `:async`, it's cleared out of memory when the process ends.

> Rails itself only provides an in-process queuing system, which only
>   keeps the jobs in RAM. If the process crashes or the machine is reset,
>   then all outstanding jobs are lost with the default async back-end.

Rake processes end when they're over. So, if you're doing any sort of data changes, rake tasks won't be open long enough to run a job, which is why they run `:inline` just fine, but not `:async`.

So, I haven't figured out a solution to keep rake tasks open long enough to run something `:async` (and keep the app `:async` the entire time). I have to switch it to `:inline` to run tasks, and then back to `:async` when I'm done for the rest of my jobs. It's why it works fine with `:sidekiq` or `:resque`, because those applications keep the job information in memory and do not release when the rake task is over.

In order for rake tasks to work with `:async` locally, there's not much you can do other than run tasks as `:inline` if you're local until rake (as a task runner) understands how to stay open while asynchronous tasks have been launched (or not). As a development only feature, this isn't really high priority, but, if you're bashing your head on the table not understanding why `:async` by default tasks that run jobs won't actually run, that's why.

Comment: @januszm glad I could get you a little assistance.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what you can put at the end of a rake task to wait for the AsyncAdapter to finish processing before exiting the rake task:

```
if Rails.configuration.active_job.queue_adapter == :async
  executor =
    ActiveJob::Base._queue_adapter.instance_eval do
      @scheduler.instance_eval { @async_executor }
    end
  sleep(0.1) while executor.scheduled_task_count > executor.completed_task_count
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the issue that when performing `async`, the jobs are being handled in the background, and the task is not waiting for the.

Others have given somewhat complex ways of waiting for the jobs to finish in a test even if runnimg them async.

But Rails actually has a built-in way to do this. With `perform_enqueued_jobs` you can run :async jobs but wait for them to complete, without having to assign your own custom adapter.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.0/classes/ActiveJob/TestHelper.html

> Performs all enqueued jobs. If a block is given, performs all of the jobs that were enqueued throughout the duration of the block. If a block is not given, performs all of the enqueued jobs up to this point in the test.

```
def test_perform_enqueued_jobs
  perform_enqueued_jobs do
    MyJob.perform_later(1, 2, 3)
  end
  assert_performed_jobs 1
end

def test_perform_enqueued_jobs_without_block
  MyJob.perform_later(1, 2, 3)

  perform_enqueued_jobs

  assert_performed_jobs 1
end
```

For `rspec`, just had to `include ActiveJob::TestHelper` inside the `describe` block.